# ZeroC Ice "checked casts" in Scala

Tags: scala, types, ice

ZeroC Ice for Java [translates](http://www.zeroc.com/doc/Ice-3.4.0/manual/Java.11.11.html) every Slice interface `Simple` into (among other things) a proxy interface `SimplePrx` and a proxy `SimplePrxHelper`. If I have an `ObjectPrx` (the base interface for all proxies), I can check whether it actually has interface `Simple` by using a static method on `SimplePrxHelper`:

```
val obj : Ice.ObjectPrx = ...;        // Get a proxy from somewhere...

val simple : SimplePrx = SimplePrxHelper.checkedCast(obj);
if (simple != null)
    // Object supports the Simple interface...
else
    // Object is not of type Simple...
```

I wanted to write a method `castTo` so that I could replace the second line with

```
val simple = castTo[SimplePrx](obj)
```

or

```
val simple = castTo[SimplePrxHelper](obj)
```

So far as I can see, Scala's type system is not expressive enough to allow me to define `castTo`. Is this correct?

Comment: Why not just `val simple = SimplePrxHelper.checkedCast(obj)`?  It's almost as short as what you want.  Otherwise, it's not clear to me how the _type_ system is supposed to know that this particular library has defined a relationship between things called `FooPrx` and `FooPrxHelper`, given that the library is organized that way and not as `Helper<FooPrx>` like it "should" be.

Comment: Because I am less worried about being short than about being generic. I can't, e.g., use such a cast inside a method `foo[AProxyInterface]() : AProxyInterface`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be able to do something with implicits, along these lines:

```
object Casting {
  trait Caster[A] {
    def checkedCast(obj: ObjectPrx): Option[A]
  }

  def castTo[A](obj: ObjectPrx)(implicit caster: Caster[A]) =
    caster.checkedCast(obj)

  implicit object SimplePrxCaster extends Caster[SimplePrx] {
    def checkedCast(obj: ObjectPrx) = Option(SimplePrxHelper.checkedCast(obj))
  }
}
```

Then you just bring things into scope where you want to use them:

```
package my.package

import Casting._

...
  def whatever(prx: ObjectPrx) {
    castTo[SimplePrx](prx) foreach (_.somethingSimple())
  }
...
```

Comment: For that matter, if you don't like all the "implicit objects" lying around, you could do it this way:

    def castTo[A](obj: ObjectPrx)(implicit mfst: ClassManifest[A]) = {
      val helperClass = Class.forName(mfst.erasure.getName + "Helper");
      val method = helperClass.getMethod("checkedCast", classOf[ObjectPrx]);
      Option(method.invoke(null, obj)).asInstanceOf[Option[A]]
    }

..plus exception handling of course.  Not as type safe thanks to the erased cast, and rather slower, but only one named thing.

Edit: eek, formatting fail!

Answer (score 1):

You can get something like what you want with structural types:

```
def castTo[A](helper: { def checkedCast(o: Object): A })(o: Object) = {
  helper.checkedCast(o)
}
class FooPrx { }
object FooPrxHelper {
  def checkedCast(o: Object): FooPrx = o match {
    case fp : FooPrx => fp
    case _ => null
  }
}

scala> val o: Object = new FooPrx
o: java.lang.Object = FooPrx@da8742

scala> val fp = castTo(FooPrxHelper)(o)
fp: FooPrx = FooPrx@da8742
```

Comment: I did think of this, but unfortunately `FooPrxHelper` is defined as a class (in Java). I got "FooPrxHelper is not a value".

Comment: @Alexey You could wrap everything by hand (or not really by hand--write something that will do the automatic code generation for you).